# When I update ASP.NET MVC from 5.0 to 5.1, do I need to update the bindingRedirect to 5.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Should this...

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

...become this?

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Or should I leave it alone?

What about when I update Razor from 3.0 to 3.1?

Should this...

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

...become this?

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.1.0.0" />
```

Or should I leave it alone?

What about when I go from 5.1.1 and 3.1.1 respectively? Should I be as granular as possible in my web.configs, or leave them at their major revisions? It seems to work both ways!

Late add:

And what the heck is going on here?
[image: weird version numbers]

It says 5.1.1 in the path to the assembly, but 5.1.0.0 in the Version. Which number should I be using in the Web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to MVC, no to WebPages. WebPages assembly version did not change, it was only a NuGet package version upgrade.

On Web.config always use the assembly version, not the package version. I don't think they'll use the patch part on the assembly version, only on the package version.

Comment: Okay, and the version mismatch in my graphic would indicate that the MVC assembly stays at 5.1 when the package is upgraded to 5.1.1, correct?